# Create custom ribbon group with JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom, ribbon

With  `oList.get_userCustomActions().add();` I create custom icons/buttons in an existing ribbon using JSOM.

How can I create a custom ribbon group in an existing ribbon via JSOM?

Comment: According to the documentation the function get_userCustomActions() has a property called set_group where you can indicate the group, try to use it

Comment: Thanks for your comment, didn't quite work, i.e. no group created. May I ask you for your source?

Comment: You may also want to check that helper I've created: https://github.com/Aymkdn/RibbonPlus

Comment: @AymKdn thx I'll have a look at it!